# how to set label of dynamically created StaticText in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm learning wx and I've got a problem like this: let's say I create few StaticText objects and then I want to change its labels on some events.
example:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        for i in range(5):
            self.button=wx.Button(self.panel, -1, label='b'+str(i), pos=(20,30*i))
            self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)
            self.label=wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, label='label'+str(i), pos=(120,30*i), name='label'+str(i))

    def on_button(self, event):
        b=event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()
        if b.endswith('1'):
            self.label1.SetLabel('sss')

x=wx.App()
y=MyFrame(None).Show()
x.MainLoop()
```

so, as you can see I want to change label of self.label1 I've created earlier, and I can't do that because of an error: in on_button; 
AttributeError: 'MyFrame' object has no attribute 'label1'

I think I have to change something while creating objects but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first issue is that on each iteration through the for loop, you overwrite the self.button and the self.label instances. You never create a variable called "self.label1". There are a couple of approaches to fix this. Here's one simple way to do it:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        for i in range(5):
            self.button=wx.Button(self.panel, -1, label='b'+str(i), pos=(20,30*i))
            self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)
            self.label=wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, label='label'+str(i), pos=(120,30*i), name='label'+str(i))

    def on_button(self, event):
        b=event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()

        if b.endswith('1'):
            newLabel = "sss"
            self.resetLabel('1', newLabel)
        elif b.endswith('2'):
            self.resetLabel('2', "Number 2!")

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def resetLabel(self, number, newLabel):
        """"""
        lbls = [widget for widget in self.panel.GetChildren() if isinstance(widget, wx.StaticText)]
        for lbl in lbls:
            if number in lbl.GetLabel():
                lbl.SetLabel(newLabel)
                break

x=wx.App()
y=MyFrame(None).Show()
x.MainLoop()
```

You could also use setattr and getattr to create the self.label(1-N) dynamically like this:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        for i in range(5):
            setattr(self, "button%s" % i, 
                    wx.Button(self.panel, -1, label='b'+str(i), pos=(20,30*i))
                    )
            btn = getattr(self, "button%s" % i)
            btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)
            setattr(self, "label%s" % i,
                    wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, label='label'+str(i), pos=(120,30*i), name='label'+str(i))
                    )
        print

    def on_button(self, event):
        b=event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()

        if b.endswith('1'):
            self.label1.SetLabel("sss")
        elif b.endswith('2'):
            self.label2.SetLabel("Number 2!")



x=wx.App()
y=MyFrame(None).Show()
x.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dict to map buttons to labels:

```
self.label[button] = label
```

Then, given an event associated with a button, you can find the associated label:

```
    button = event.GetEventObject()
    label = self.label[button]
```

---

```
import wx


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.label = {}
        for i in range(5):
            button = wx.Button(
                self.panel, -1, label='b' + str(i), pos=(20, 30 * i))
            button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)
            label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, label='label' + str(
                i), pos=(120, 30 * i), name='label' + str(i))
            self.label[button] = label

    def on_button(self, event):
        button = event.GetEventObject()
        label = self.label[button]
        label.SetLabel('sss')

x = wx.App()
y = MyFrame(None).Show()
x.MainLoop()
```

Comment: that's also great solution. I haven't even thought about using dictionaries